# javafx - Separate EventHandler and gui code

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, implementation, eventhandler

So i would like to know how i can separate Events in a class and have the GUI code in another class without them having direct knowledge of eachother.
I have recently only been working in one class , where i have been putting GUI code and listeners in the start method.

this is what iv'e done so far but the button dosen't work:

GUI class:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class GUI extends Application {

Button btn1 = new Button("press me");

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

        root.setCenter(btn1);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


       } catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Controller class:

```
package application;

import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

public class Control implements EventHandler<Event>{

GUI gui;

public Control(GUI gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
}

@Override
public void handle(Event event) {
    Object cmd = event.getSource();
    if(gui.btn1.equals(cmd)){
        System.out.println("your pressed btn1");
      }
   }

}
```

Main class:

```
package application;

public class Main extends GUI {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

    GUI gui = new GUI();
    Control control = new Control(gui);
   }
}
```

Comment: You are not setting the event Handler to the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the control class as event handler for button..

```
button.setOnAction(new Control(this )) ;
```

Comment: If it works and is a solution to your problem accept the answer.. So that others will also be benefitted